# How to handle external arbitrary class-type handlers in GUI testing library?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, automated-tests

I'm trying to invent a GUI testing library for Qt. The library is meant to work remotely, so that I can run tests on mobile devices over WiFi. It should simply provide API for visible element's functions.

It should be extensible. In Qt, any visible GUI element is subclass of `QWidget`. I can hard-code handling for `QPushButton` (eg. clicking) or `QLineEdit` (writing text) but note that user can define his or her own `QWidget` subclasses, some of which may represent completely new kind of GUI.

In Java, I could solve this because class type is essentially a variable of `Class` type. So I could have:

```
  public static void registerTestingHandler(Class<? extends java.awt.Component> GUIObject, Class<? extends TestingApi> apiHandler) {
    ...
  }
```

The `TestingApi` would then be some basic interface which would accept messages as strings, eg: `handler.doAction("click");`

C++ doesn't have this kind of reflection. I also learned that it's impossible to get class' constructor address which could be used for this purpose. I think the whole design should probably look different in C++.

Therefore the question is: How do I allow user to register abstract handlers for specific class instances?

Comment: Not that familiar with Java anymore: do you want the two arguments to be Objects of classes inheriting from QWidget/TestingApi? Or just the classes themselve?

Comment: Yes, they must inherit. The testing API handler must have a known method for handling commands (eg. click) and the GUI instance must be distinguishable as specific type, so user can make his own UI type and register handler for it's actions.

Comment: I think you should try to (ab)use accesibility API, which typically provide functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @el.pescado I'm not sure what are you referring to. Typically accessibility refers to certain level of user comfort or the comfort for disabled users.

Comment: That's what I'm referring to. Assistive technologies such as screen readers for sight-impaired users require access to GUI elements, which in turn can be used by tools such as [LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/).